# Generators of $Rep(G)$

Tags: algebraic-groups, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Rep(G)$ the category of rational representations.
Is there a "nice" (let's say combinatorical) description of the generators of $Rep(G)$ as a tensor category?

Comment: You can work over any algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 if you want (this ensures complete reducibiity of representations). If `$G$` is *semisimple* and *simply connected*, the finite dimensional irreducible representations with a fundamental highest weight may suffice for your purpose.  Removing the simply connected condition complicates the picture somewhat.   Adding a central torus is a further complication, even though its irreducible rational representations are just characters.   So it's useful to make your assumptions as precise as possible.   

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Semisimple and simply connected is a start. Do you know any reference on this? Anyway i would be really interested why the situation in the non simply connected case is harder. Again, i would appreciate any reference. Best, Oliver.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generators of $Rep(G)$ as a tensor category": do you allow the operation of taking sub-representation in the way you generate? Do you want generators for the objects of $Rep(G)$, and generators for the morphisms of $Rep(G)$?

Comment: Yes taking sub-representations would be fine.  Also it would be enough to have generators for the objects. 

Comment: @O.: Irreps are parametrized by dominant integral highest weights, formalized in the *representation ring* (Grothendieck ring).  For a simply connected semisimple group (or compact Lie group), it's equivalent to work with the Lie algebra; e.g. *Brocker & tom Dieck *Representations of Compact Lie Groups*, II.7. or Bourbaki *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*, Chap. 8, section 7 (and exercise 27).  Fundamental dominant weights yield standard "generators".  For a not simply connected group, limit to dominant weights in cosets of the weight lattice mod root lattice. (No easy "generators".)   